# Rails server traffic blocked by heavy writing to MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm executing a script from the rails console; the script crawls a MySQL database, creating ~.5 million MongoDB documents.

I've noticed that when running `rails server` while the script is running, any request's response must wait on thousands of lines of output from MOPED, e.g.:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=survey_app_development collection=mongo_surveys selector={"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b3", "questions._id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b5"} update={"$set"=>{"questions.1.response"=>{"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5bd", "data"=>{"datepicker"=>"10/21/2011", "response"=>1319216400}, "comment"=>nil}}} flags=[] (0.0000ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=survey_app_development collection=mongo_surveys selector={"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b3", "questions._id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b6"} update={"$set"=>{"questions.2.response"=>{"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5be", "data"=>{"response"=>"Morning"}, "comment"=>nil}}} flags=[] (0.0000ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=survey_app_development collection=mongo_surveys selector={"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b3", "questions._id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b7"} update={"$set"=>{"questions.3.response"=>{"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5bf", "data"=>{"0"=>"yes", "1"=>"no", "2"=>"no", "3"=>"no"}, "comment"=>""}}} flags=[] (0.0000ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=survey_app_development collection=mongo_surveys selector={"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b3", "questions._id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b8"} update={"$set"=>{"questions.4.response"=>{"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5c0", "data"=>{"response"=>"outdoor"}, "comment"=>""}}} flags=[] (0.0000ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=survey_app_development collection=mongo_surveys selector={"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b3", "questions._id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b9"} update={"$set"=>{"questions.5.response"=>{"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5c1", "data"=>{"response"=>"5"}, "comment"=>nil}}} flags=[] (0.0000ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=survey_app_development collection=mongo_surveys selector={"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5b3", "questions._id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5ba"} update={"$set"=>{"questions.6.response"=>{"_id"=>"509043ec2c5f64685b62c5c2", "data"=>{"response"=>"attest"}, "comment"=>nil}}} flags=[] (1.0002ms)
```

If I let the script execute long enough (with rails server running), any http request results in:

```
[2012-10-30 16:24:44] ERROR Java heap space
[2012-10-30 16:25:12] ERROR Java heap space
[2012-10-30 16:26:11] ERROR Java heap space
```

So, my question is: Is there a setting to prevent this behavior?  Also, should I expect the server traffic to be impeded when writing to MongoDB?

I am using *Mongoid*, *Rails 3.2*, and *JRuby 1.7.0*, *MongoDB 2.2.0*

Comment: it's all local right now... I'm doing front end development while the script executes. Still, I would expect similar behavior with 10k concurrent users all writing data to MongoDB.

Comment: What version of mongo are you running? (run `mongo --version`)

Comment: v2.2.0 (edited question to reflect)

Comment: so 500k docs in one batch? what is the avg set size? default write behavior? profiling on? verbosity of logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB only allows a single operation to be writing at a time.  The scope of this write lock varies from version to version -- it used to be the whole server but has been getting finer-grained in recent versions.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

That said, the lock should be released after every `update` command.  So your rails server should be able to field requests with delays comparable to individual update commands from your script.  If not, something else must be going on.

I recommend installing [MMS](https://mms.10gen.com/) and watch the graphs for lock % and queue length to see how backed up things are getting because of the write lock.